# 'Insert SparkSession DataFrame' automatically converting data from integer to float in DSX

Tags: apache-spark-sql, data-science-experience

I have a csv file which I insert to IBM Data Science Experience using "SparkSession DataFrame". All content in the csv file (other than the headers) are integers.

The dataframe works as expected though certain Machine Learning models until trying to create a Linear Regression Classification where I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('U32') according to the rule 'safe'

I believe this means that the data is no longer an integer and is being treated as a float.

How can I resolve this? Is there anything that can be done when you import the file to make sure it stays as an integer? See example below where I tried to add in a second option for format.

```
`from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.read\
  .format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat')\
  .option('header', 'true')\
  .option('format', 'int32')\
  .load(bmos.url('name', 'name.csv'))
df.take(5)`
```

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me.

Are you getting the TypeError as a result of just the code snippet you posted?

Comment: You need to use .option('inferSchema', 'true')  instead of format for spark csv connector to infer the schema...it will infer integer type for you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9114719/emmajdaws if this resolved your question can you mark it answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@charles-gomes is correct. Here's a complete example where my file `tinyinttest.csv` is in an objectstore container called `TestingSandbox`. 
Contents of `tinyinttest.csv` is:

```
name,val
a,1
b,2
```

---

code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import ibmos2spark

credentials = {
    'auth_url': 'https://identity.open.softlayer.com',
    'project_id': 'xxx',
    'region': 'xxx',
    'user_id': 'xxx',
    'username': 'xxx',
    'password': 'xxx'
}

configuration_name = 'xxx'
bmos = ibmos2spark.bluemix(sc, credentials, configuration_name)
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.read\
  .format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVFileFormat')\
  .option('header', 'true')\
  .option('inferSchema', 'true')\
  .load(bmos.url('TestingSandbox', 'tinyinttest.csv'))

df.schema
```

output:

```
StructType(List(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(val,IntegerType,true)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683818/raj and apologies for my slow 'answered'. It has worked by changing to an integer.

I also realised that by importing as a Pandas Dataframe rather than SparkSession Dataframe meant I didn't have the problem with the Linear Regression Classification and seemed easier to use on the whole.